# Calculating Year over Year Growth using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using a SQL dataset called Superstore and I want to figure out how to calculate year over year sales growth as a percentage. Here's the code I already have:

```sql
SELECT 
EXTRACT(year FROM order_date) AS order_year,
SUM(sales) AS total_sales,
FROM orders
WHERE order_date BETWEEN date '2016-01-01' and date '2019-12-01'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Any help would be welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to explain your issue, add actual output and desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

I would aggregate in a subquery, then use a window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT total_sales / lag(total_sales) OVER (ORDER BY order_year) * 100.0,
             year
      FROM (SELECT CAST (EXTRACT(year FROM order_date) AS integer) AS order_year,
                   SUM(sales) AS total_sales
            FROM orders
            GROUP BY 1) AS subq
     ) AS subq2
WHERE year = 2021;
```